# Python lambda function over a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Creating a lambda that will perform 2 tests on the input.  Test 1 is easy--just need to know if the input, b, is in a list called `pats`.  If that test is false then it should test if the input has a match in the list `wcardpats` according fo `fnmatch.filter([b],`ANY ENTRY IN WCARDPATS).  I am using [b] because b will not be a list but `fnmatch.filter()` takes a list of filenames as the first parameter and the pattern to test as the second parameter.

```
`lambda b: b in pats` OR THE SECOND TEST
```

So when I use the lambda I am testing that my input (b) is either in `pats`, 
or one of the entries in `wcardpats` returns a match for `fnmatch.filter([b],` 
wcardpats-entry).

I need to use fnmatch.filter() and not reg-ex.

Comment: Just define a function instead of an anonymous lambda. Much easier.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `any` function? `lambda b: b in pats or any(fnmatch.filter([b], e) for e in wcardpats)`

Comment: @Elmex80s: because this is part of a large body of code that I need to tweak.  The function currently returns a lambda that is used elsewhere.  We need to change what will count as 'true'.  I was assigned this task.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks!  I'm a newbie as far as python is concerned, but that looks like that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since I can't accept a comment as the answer I guess I will answer it myself.  @chepner is correct: `lambda b: b in pats or any(fnmatch.filter([b], e) for e in wcardpats)` works.